# Ruby haml unexpected ending error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true} do |f|
- if @pin.errors.any?
    #errors
        %h2
        = pluralize(@pin.errors.count, "errors")
        prevented this Pin from saving
        %ul
            - @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
            %li= msg
.form-group
    = f.input :title, input_html: { class: 'form-control' } 

.form-group
    = f.input :description, input_html:{ class: 'form-control' }     

= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

can someone tell me why this is returing me the error that says below for rails

> /Users/frankchen/project/pin_board/app/views/pins/_form.html.haml:17: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end ...:Util.html_safe(_erbout);ensure;@haml_buffer = @haml_buffer.... ... ^ /Users/frankchen/project/pin_board/app/views/pins/_form.html.haml:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's HAML, it's more than likely an indentation issue.  I can't match up the line number you provided since we're only seeing a snippet of the code, but I'm guessing that the indentation between these two lines is off:

```
- @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
%li= msg
```

Comment: this is actually the entire code, i have no idea why the errors are different lines

Answer (score 1):

Can't really tell if the code indentations got messed up when you pasted in your code or that's how you actually have it, but yea, you have several mis-indentations. For example:

```
= simple_form_for @pin, html: { multipart: true} do |f|
- if @pin.errors
```

That `- if` should be indented over 2 spaces. so that it's in the scope of the simple form above it. Same goes for you `ul` and its `li`s within the `each`

Comment: yea i think it messed up when i pasted it into stackoverflow, your code has the same identation

Comment: That's because i copied your code. Have you looked for indentation issues in your actual view code?

Comment: hey man, i figured it out, it looks like haml only allows for 2spaces identation for the codes to run? i changed my sublime settings for tabs to return only 2 spaces for identation

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked when I remove the indentation between `%ul` and `- @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|`. I still don't know the reason though since the `- @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|` is supposed to be inside the `@ul` tag.

```
%ul
- @pin.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
  %li= msg
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a single missed quote:

```
= link_to 'How to create an offer, '#', class: 'icu-card-title-link card-title'
```